# Categorical data to edges in networkx

Tags: networkx

I am trying to color the edges in a networkx graph.

I am having trouble with the edge colorings -- I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: edge_color must be a single color or list of exactly m colors where m is the number or edges
```

This is what I have to create the graph:

```
nx_plot = pd.concat([s_comms, s_survs, s_eng])
nx_plot['Order'] = pd.Categorical(nx_plot['Order'])

plt.figure(figsize = (12, 10))
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(nx_plot, 'From', 'To', create_using = nx.Graph())
nx.draw(G, node_color = 'black', alpha = 0.3, node_size = 3, edge_color = nx_plot['Order'].cat.codes, edge_cmap = plt.cm.Blues)
plt.show()
```

where nx_plot is a pandas dataframe that has the columns 'To', 'From', and 'Order'.

I'm not sure what is going on, I had followed a [small tutorial](https://python-graph-gallery.com/325-map-colour-to-the-edges-of-a-network/) to create these. nx_plot['Order'] is the category being mapped to the edges, it has 4 distinct categories in it.

Comment: can you print `nx_plot['Order'].cat.codes`?  The error message is saying that either needs to be a color or a list of colors with the same length as the edge list (and you're likely also going to have trouble because it needs to be in the same order as the edgelist).

Comment: Yes I've tried printing it, it prints the dataframe column with the codes and says it has the length of the full dataframe.

Comment: can you add it to your post?  It should simply be a list of colors.  So it sounds like this is your problem.

Comment: I see -- I've just checked the length of G.edges and it is slightly shorter than the length of the dataframe that is being used to generate the edges. Is there a way to automatically line those up? I guess I'm not entirely clear why it is being shortened (I'm assuming duplicates, possibly?).

Edit: I've just checked the nx_plot df and it only has one duplicate in it, so that is not the issue.

Comment: Until I see what `nx_plot['Order'].cat.codes`, I can't help much except to say that the way you have described it, it does not sound like it's a list of colors.  Does it take the form `['red', 'blue', 'green', ...]` or not?